# Fantasy novel where students are tested for special abilities and symbols and are taken

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book starts with a rainy day, the house they live in is surrounded by vines and wild life. The father, I believe was an alcoholic. The students get tested for abilities and if they have the forbidden ability they are taken and never seen again.

The girl is tested and she has the ability symbol. The higher up people come after her and her father lets her to escape. While escaping she is saved by a guy. The guy has two personalities or minds in one body. One is his brother. He is with a group of escapees or outcasts. They live in a metal warehouse type building.

The girl and the guy start to fall for each other. The group's other girl starts to get jealous. The higher people start to come after them. While hiding out they are attacked by dark shadow people or demons. The brother or main one is injured and might die.

They are hiding out in an abandoned building.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What were the special abilities? What did the 'ability symbol' look like and where on the body was it found? What were the names of the characters? Why were they hiding/on the run? Who were the higher-up people (govt, CIA, shadowy organisation with silly name)? Was this book written for YA audience or was it more adult (with sex and violence)? What did the cover look like?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  In addition to the questions Valorum has asked above, this can help us narrow down the search.